# view requires API level 14 (Current min is 1)

Tags: android-layout

I am new in android , when i try to run my application at that time error occurs below

```
View requires API level 14 (current min is 1): <GridLayout>
```

and i was put the

uses-sdk  `android:minSdkVersion="14"`  `android:targetSdkVersion="19"`

in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Can anybody guide to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Grid Layout requires atleast api level 14](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html)

so the min sdk version should be 14 or +, otherwise you cannot use that grid layout. Most commonly using devices having api level from 8 + , so it is better to replace grid layout to some other views based on your requirement.